# DateTime.ParseExact() does not grok 24-hour time values?

Tags: c#, datetime, cultureinfo

This line of code:

```
DateTime dt = DateTime.ParseExact(time, "hh:mm", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
```

parses a "time" value of "12:45" just fine, but throws an exception of "13:00"

Should I be using some other CultureInfo value, or do I need to append a "pm" to hour values above 12, or ... ?

Error message is: *System.FormatException was unhandled
  Message=String was not recognized as a valid DateTime.*

Comment: Use "HH:mm" to parse 24 hour formats.

Comment: +1 for using the term "grok" in an SO question

Answer (score 69, accepted):

"hh" is the 12-hour clock format (01 to 12).  You need to use "HH" for a 24 hour clock.

```
DateTime dt = DateTime.ParseExact(time, "HH:mm", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
```

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
DateTime dt = DateTime.ParseExact(time, "u", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
```

`"u"` indicates universal sortable format.

Answer (score 2):

Though Hans already answered your question in comment section, [Here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.globalization.datetimeformatinfo.aspx) is an MSDN link describing all kinds of date formats used with `DateTime.ParseExact` method.