# parse 11/06/2020 - 18:13 to datetime

Tags: c#, datetime

I am trying to parse the following format to a datetime:

```
11/06/2020 - 18:13
```

I tried:

```
DateTime t= DateTime.ParseExact(data[i][j], "dd/MM/yyyy - hh:mm", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
```

but it gives exception:

> System.FormatException: 'String was not recognized as a valid DateTime.'

Comment: Does this answer your question? [DateTime.ParseExact() does not grok 24-hour time values?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11232385/datetime-parseexact-does-not-grok-24-hour-time-values) The exact duplicate as well as [How to Parse a DateTime String to Support 24 hours timing?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17107230/how-to-parse-a-datetime-string-to-support-24-hours-timing)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to specify 24 hour time `HH`

```
DateTime.ParseExact(input, "dd/MM/yyyy - HH:mm", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
```

[The "HH" custom format specifier](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/base-types/custom-date-and-time-format-strings#HH_Specifier)

> The "HH" custom format specifier (plus any number of additional "H"
>   specifiers) represents the hour as a number from 00 through 23; that
>   is, the hour is represented by a zero-based 24-hour clock that counts
>   the hours since midnight. A single-digit hour is formatted with a
>   leading zero.